# Change time precision in column

Tags: r

I have a column in my datafame that displays time values like this:

```
05:20:45.154
```

How can I change the number of milliseconds to look like this?

```
05:20:45.2
```

Thanks

Comment: https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/round_date.html

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

You could `strsplit` and round the third element.

```
round_time <- function(x, r=1) {
  tmp <- el(strsplit(tm, ':'))
  tmp[3] <- round(as.numeric(tmp[3]), r)
  paste(tmp, collapse=':')
}

round_time('05:20:45.154')
# [1] "05:20:45.2"
```

The function `strftime` with `%OS1` seems to truncate the miliseconds instead of rounding them.

```
strftime(as.POSIXct(paste(Sys.Date(), '05:20:45.154')), format='%H:%M:%OS1')
# [1] "05:20:45.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach with `sub`and `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(time = paste0(sub("^(.{6}).*", "\\1", time), 
                       round(as.numeric(sub(".*(.{6})", "\\1", time)),1)))
        time
1 05:20:45.2
2 12:15:40.8
```

Here's how this works:

You `paste0` together two substrings that you capture using backreference `\\1`:

- `^(.{6}).*`: this is the hours and minutes followed by `:`
- `.*(.{6})`: this is the seconds and the milliseconds

Additionally, we convert this second string into type numeric so that we can `round` it to one decimal. The function `paste0` puts the two pieces back again.

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  time = c("05:20:45.154", "12:15:40.841")
)
```